# Why does .replace() in javascript replace the "the" in then?

Tags: javascript, regex

if I did

```
var x="the dog then the cat ran";
var y=x.replace(/the/g,"");
```

then y would equal

```
"dog n cat ran"
```

The n would remain after having the letters "the" removed (or replaced) from then.

How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: Put spaces on each side of the replace: var y=x.replace(/\sthe\s/g,"");     The answer below is better though, use that!

Comment: Note that this isn't really a JavaScript question, it's a basic regular expression question about why a particular regex matches certain text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add boundary markers, like this:

```
var x="the dog then the cat ran";
var y=x.replace(/\bthe\b/g,"");
// y = " dog then  cat ran"
```

Otherwise, `/the/` matches `then`, `breathe`, `thesis`, etc., just as easily as `the`. `\b` requires a word boundary.

If you *want* to get rid of `then` as well, try this:

```
var x="the dog then the cat ran";
var y=x.replace(/\bthe\S*\b/g,"");
// y = " dog    cat ran"
```

To get rid of the excess spaces:

```
var x="the dog then the cat ran";
var y=x.replace(/\bthe\S*\b\s*/g,"");
// y = "dog cat ran"
```